# Android Button color changes

Tags: android, button

I want to change the button color when some one starts to fill the requirement fields.

Button color should be set to a color, when fields are blank, meaning the button is not clickable. Button color should be changed when the fields are filled.

Comment: At least ask question properly....

Answer (score 0):

```
yourButton.setEnabled(true/false)
yourButton.setBackgroundDrawable(yourButton.isEnabled() ? R.drawable.yourDrawbleActive: R.drawable.yourDrawbleUnActive)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add textWatcher on your required editable field. you will be notified about text changes then change the color of button as you want.